# Why platform ready event doesn't fire in Capacitor?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have just installed [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/) and it seems there is no need to add platform ready event. I have tried this code:

```
  async initializeApp() {
    await Browser.open({
      url: 'https://www.google.com'
    });
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('ready');
    });
  }
```

Whatever i add inside ready event, it doesnt fire (like cordova). And it seems i am able to call the native apis directly without ready event. However, if we use cordova plugins, where we are supposed to call them ? 
**Edit**:
there seems to be an issue in V4.Alpha7 as described [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14489#issuecomment-395539968).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you said, this was an Ionic 4 bug and it's fixed now.

About when to call Cordova plugins, same way as Capacitor plugins, you can call them as soon as the app launches without waiting for ready event.

But once the fix is releases you can also keep the ready code if you want. It will work the same way as ready will also be called as soon as your app launches.

Comment: i guess cordova plugins are waiting for platform ready. They aren't available before that. Is it changed in capacitor like so ?

Comment: yeah, that changes in Capacitor, you can use them as soon as the app launches because it uses WKWebView, which allows code injection, so code is injected and you don't have to wait. It still fires ready event to keep Cordova compatibility, but it's fired right away.

Comment: wow i didn't know it. May i have any link to this ? or code on github... ?

Comment: yeah, here is where the code is injected on the WKWebView https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/master/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/JSExport.swift#L157-L165

Answer (score 0):

I believe now you can use this:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {  
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(/* register your plugins here*/);
  }
}
```